# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou usando Vue.js e me deparei com o erro do título.

Tenho um objeto com array:

```
students[
          contact: {
            mobile: null,
            phone: null
          }
        ],
```

O array `contact` nem sempre é preenchido.

Como faço para não dar `TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined` quando o array não tiver sido criado?

Tentei adicionar no mais também não deu:

```
mounted () {
   this.students.contact.fone = ''},
```

Comment: mas `students` nem é um array...

Comment: colei errado ajustei

Comment: Mas ainda está errado... Deveria ser: `[{contact: { mobile: null, phone: null } }]`. E depois você acessa assim:  `this.students[0].contact.fone`

Comment: Na onde está declarado este array, no **data**? Faz um **methods** ou um **computed** para verificar se o array está preenchido. Se tiver preenchido faz tal coisa senão faz outra coisa.

Comment: Fiz da seguinte forma e chamei no created, porem continua o mesmo erro:  verificar () {
        if (!this.students.contact) {
          this.students.contact.phone = 0
          this.students.contact.mobile = 0
        }
      },

Comment: Tá acessando errado ainda... É um **array** que quer acessar, tem que acessar a propriedade utilizando um índice **[]**

Comment: entendi. mudei para:
verificar () {
        if (!this.students[0].contact) {
          this.students[0].contact.phone = 0
          this.students[0].contact.mobile = 0
        }
      },
mesmo erro ainda

Comment: Vale observar que a key é "phone" e não "fone".

Comment: Seria mais fácil e rápido te ajudar se você montar um exemplo funcionando e postar editando a pergunta. De preferência um exemplo mínimo, só com código o suficiente para reproduzir o erro.

Comment: Olha só [esse exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/372318/) funciona perfeitamente. Por isso precisamos ver mais seu código para descobrir onde está o erro